# How to initialize a vector<bool> with values 01 repeating?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

Can I initialize a `vector<bool>` to start with a sequence of 010101...etc?  Or do I have to just initialize it with 0's and loop thru and change every other value to 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on @zmbq's answer, use `std::generate_n` like this:

```
std::vector<bool> v;
v.reserve(desired_size);

bool b = true;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), desired_size, [&b]() { return (b = !b); });
```

You would use `std::generate` if the `vector` already *had* a size.

If you don't have a C++11 compiler...

```
std::vector<bool> v;
v.reserve(desired_size);

struct GenFn
{
   GenFn(bool b = true)
      : b(b)
   {
   }

   bool operator()() const
   {
      return (b = !b);
   }

private:
   bool b;
};

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), desired_size, GenFn());
```

Comment: "You would use std::generate if the vector already had a size" -- and although you don't have to, you might want to `reserve` first even with a 0-size vector.

Comment: Since there's a decent chance that the non-C++11 example might be copy-pasted somewhere, it might be a good idea to have the generator functor be a named type rather than an instance of an anonymous type (so if it gets reused it won't 'remember' state from its last use), and it should have at least one user specified constructor (even if it's a user-defined default ctor) so `b` will be sure to be initialized.

Comment: Fair enough. The initialization step is definitely something necessary that I skipped because I was sleepy and got lazy. :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [generate](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/generate.html).

Answer (score 2):

inspired by zmbq, I wrote this and it works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool fill01()
{
    static int val=1;
    val=++val%2;
    return val==0?false:true;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<bool> ve(100);
    std::generate(ve.begin(), ve.end(), fill01);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (code not tested, might be buggy). It's basically the same as mos's `generate_n`, but by a different route. It's probably obvious that by comparison to `generate_n`, this is only worth doing if you can get some other use out of `flipflop_iterator`:

```
struct flipflop_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, bool> {
    bool offset; // make sure the first value is false
    size_t remaining;
    flipflop_iterator(size_t length) : offset(length % 2), remaining(length) {}
    flipflop_iterator &operator++() {
        --remaining;
        return *this;
    }
    flipflop_iterator operator++(int) {
        flipflop_iterator tmp(*this); 
        ++(*this); 
        return tmp; 
    }
    bool operator*() const { 
        return (remaining + offset) % 2;
    }
    bool operator==(const flipflop_iterator &rhs) const {
        return remaining == rhs.remaining;
    }
    bool operator!=(const flipflop_iterator &rhs) const {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
};

std::vector<bool> v(flipflop_iterator(100), flipflop_iterator(0));
```

You could get a performance improvement by making `flipflop_iterator` a random access iterator instead of a forward iterator, but I can't be bothered to write out all those member functions. In that case it would probably be better to build it out of a `boost::counting_iterator` and a `boost::transform_iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool bool_array[] = {true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false};
    vector<bool> bVec;
    bVec.insert(bVec.begin(),bool_array,&bool_array[sizeof(bool_array)/ sizeof(*bool_array)]);
    for(int i=0;i<bVec.size();++i){
        cout<<"At pos :"<<i<<" Val is:"<<bVec[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
At pos :0 Val is:1
At pos :1 Val is:0
At pos :2 Val is:1
At pos :3 Val is:0
At pos :4 Val is:1
At pos :5 Val is:0
At pos :6 Val is:1
At pos :7 Val is:0
```

Comment: would it be faster to use the constructor that does that instead of using insert?  it's a big vector.